# Reading from a file into an array using a for loop then printing back in again

Tags: c, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays one for the questions and one for the answers. They are stored in the structure "qa". I want the programme to ask each question and then to  scan each answer into a new file.

```
 typedef struct{
  char q[40][250];
  char a[40][250];
} qa;

int main()
{

   char b [40][250];
   int w, e, r, t, k, l;
   char a1[40][250];

   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("quest.txt", "r");

   for(int w = 0; w < 27; ++w){
      printf("%s", b[l]);
      scanf("%s", a1[l]);
   }

   for(t=0;t<41;t++){
     strncpy(qa[k].q, b[l], 250);
     strncpy(qa[k].a, a1[l], 250);
   }

       fwrite(&qa, sizeof(qa), 1, fp);

       fclose(fp);
   }
```

I have made these edits after going away and the error im getting is "expected expression before ‘questans’
      strncpy(questans[k].question, buff[i], 250);" and "too few arguments to function ‘strncpy’
      strncpy(questans[k].question, buff[i], 250);"

Comment: you do not check if `fopen()` worked.`a` is used uninitiallized. what is the for loop (with `k` doing? And regarding your error you should read how structs are defined and used.

Comment: The for look with k is looping the questions and the answers. I thought that .a would call the function?

Comment: i talk about int `a` used in `store[a]`. And yes the for loop prints 27 times the same thing. I think you have to get a better understanding of C first before you try this.

Comment: A program is not an unrelated sequence of statements. Currently I cannot even guess what you are trying to do exacty... As a C beginner, you should first describe exactly what you want in pseudo code (open a file in *read* mode, loop reading a line until end of file, etc.). Then when you are sure that the algorithm looks good, try to translate it in C. Your current code is such a mess that I cannot even help you to fix it. Sorry to be a bit hard but you seem to lack too much basics in C language...

Comment: Ive just edited the question can one of you take a look and try and advise please?

Comment: I don't see any "questans". At what lines do the errors occur?